# C# Serialization with repeating Nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have to serialize a class to achieve below format.  Values that
    appear in 'repeatnode' are fetched from DB.  Could anyone help me
    form a class serialize in to below xml.  Also how the values can be
    assigned to the repeating tags.

```
<ParentNode> 
<docInfo>    
    <doc>name</doc>
    <fileInfo>
      <Date>2016-02-25T12:52:00</Date>
      <software>Export</software>
      <Creator>export</Creator>
    </fileInfo>
  </docInfo>
  <repeatnode id="XXXXXXXXXXX" idval="XXXXXXXX" idsub="XXXX">
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <namebore>namebore</namebore>
    </repeatnode>
    <repeatnode id="XXXXXXXXXXX" idval="XXXXXXXX" idsub="XXXX">
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <namebore>namebore</namebore>
    </repeatnode>
    <repeatnode id="XXXXXXXXXXX" idval="XXXXXXXX" idsub="XXXX">
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <namebore>namebore</namebore>
    </repeatnode>
</ParentNode>
```

Comment: While there are libraries around that can make XML serialization easier most of them would require a wrapper/container node around a series of repeated nodes like that, so have you tried just using `XmlDocument` directly?

Comment: A simple class would not work for you, you'll have to override the serialization, or create a method that using `XmlDocument` like @DylanNicholson said, creates the XML just like you want it.

Comment: I am using nHibernate model. So I would more or less want it to be serialized from a class. Any other suggestion for this?

Comment: So there are no ways to serialize to get a repeating xml node?

Comment: It's not that the there's no way to get it, just that most xml serialization libraries (that work from class definitions) wouldn't support combining those node at the same level as your 'docInfo' node - but if that's a special case, maybe you find one that can serialize into an XmlDocument then add that node in yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join query to the database to get the datatable below.  Then use the code below to create the xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DocName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("software", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Creator", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nodeId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("idVal", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("idSub", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nodeName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("namebore", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "name", DateTime.Parse("2016-02-25T12:52:00"), "Export", "export", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "namebore" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "name", DateTime.Parse("2016-02-25T12:52:00"), "Export", "export", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "namebore" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "name", DateTime.Parse("2016-02-25T12:52:00"), "Export", "export", "XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "namebore" });


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new { doc = x.Field<string>("DocName"), date = x.Field<DateTime>("date"), software = x.Field<string>("software"), creator = x.Field<string>("Creator") }).ToList();

            XElement parentNode = new XElement("ParentNode");
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                XElement docInfo = new XElement("docInfo", new object[] {
                    new XElement("doc", group.Key.doc),
                    new XElement("fileinfo", new object[] {
                        new XElement("Date", group.Key.date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")),
                        new XElement("softwate", group.Key.software),
                        new XElement("Creator", group.Key.creator)
                    })
                });
                parentNode.Add(docInfo);

                foreach (var row in group)
                {
                    XElement repeatnode = new XElement("repeatnode", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("id", row.Field<string>("nodeId")),
                        new XAttribute("idval", row.Field<string>("idVal")),
                        new XAttribute("idsub", row.Field<string>("idSub")),
                        new XElement("name", row.Field<string>("nodeName")),
                        new XElement("namebore", row.Field<string>("namebore"))
                    });
                    parentNode.Add(repeatnode);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```